# Node.js Multer file uploading error

Tags: node.js, multer

I am getting undefined error for mainimage 
can anyone help me how to solve this error
thing is image is uploading and renamed something from timestamp
but its not working pls help

This is app.js route

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var posts = require('./routes/posts');
var categories = require('./routes/categories');


    var app = express();

app.locals.moment = require('moment');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Handle File Uploads
app.use(multer({dest:'./public/images/uploads'}).single('mainimage'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized:true,
  resave:true
}));

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Connect-flash
app.use(flash());
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

// Make our database accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
})

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/posts', posts);
app.use('/categories', categories);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

and this is post.js route code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

router.get('/add', function(req, res, next){
    var categories = db.get('categories');

    categories.find({},{},function(err, categories){
        // console.log(categories);

        res.render('addpost',{
        "title":"Add Post",
        "categories": categories
        });
    });
});

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
    // GET FORM VALUES
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var category    = req.body.category;
    var body        = req.body.body;
    var author      = req.body.author;
    var date        = new Date();

    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.file.mainimage)
    if(req.file.mainimage){
        var mainImageOriginalName   = req.file.mainimage.originalname;
        var mainImageName           = req.file.mainimage.filename;
        var mainImageMime           = req.file.mainimage.mimetype;
        var mainImagePath           = req.file.mainimage.path;
        var mainImageExt            = req.file.mainimage.extension;
        var mainImageSize           = req.file.mainimage.size;
        // console.log(mainImageName);
    } else{
        var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
        console.log(mainImageName);
    }

    // FORM VALIDATION
    req.checkBody('title','Title field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('body','Body field is required');

    // Check Errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('addpost',{
            "errors":errors,
            "title":title,
            "body":body
        });
    } else {
        var posts = db.get('posts');

        // SUBMIT TO DB
        posts.insert({
            "title":title,
            "body":body,
            "category":category,
            "date":date,
            "author":author,
            "mainimage":mainImageName
        }, function(err, post){
            if(err){
                res.send('There is an issue submiting the post');
            } else {
                req.flash('Success','Post submitted');
                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is addpost.jade file

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype="multipart/form-data")
        .form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
        .form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name=body, id='body')
        .form-group
            label Main Image:
            input.form-control(name='mainimage',type='file')
        .form-group
            label Author:
            select.form-control(name='author')
                option(value='Ankit Baid') Ankit Baid
                option(value='John Doe') John Doe
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit' type='submit', value='Save')
    script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
    script
        | CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```

Comment: What's `console.log(req.file)`?

Comment: this is printing this details

{ fieldname: 'mainimage',
  originalname: '1280x720-wallpapers-abstract-desktop-backgrounds-high-definition-wallpapers-art.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './public/images/uploads',
  filename: '13e14cb768ccaf0b60a539feadae5c94',
  path: 'public/images/uploads/13e14cb768ccaf0b60a539feadae5c94',
  size: 249339 }

but image is uploading in database
only this is that everytime in the database ''noimage.png " is saving

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the property `mainimage` you just need `req.file`:

```
if(req.file){
    var mainImageOriginalName   = req.file.originalname;
    var mainImageName           = req.file.filename;
    var mainImageMime           = req.file.mimetype;
    var mainImagePath           = req.file.path;
    var mainImageExt            = req.file.extension;
    var mainImageSize           = req.file.size;
    // console.log(mainImageName);
} else{
    var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
    console.log(mainImageName);
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error

image is uploading but in the database its not entering the filename

{ fieldname: 'mainimage',
  originalname: 'typography-165a.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './public/images/uploads',
  filename: 'a4e4ec724aa9b7189ebc7497f81ebf98',
  path: 'public/images/uploads/a4e4ec724aa9b7189ebc7497f81ebf98',
  size: 619043 }
noimage.png



see their in the last its showing "noimage.png"
that is only when else part is executing

Comment: Did you change the condition to `if(req.file){`?

Comment: its giving error

`Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined`

Comment: Still getting the same ans:


`{ fieldname: 'mainimage',
  originalname: 'hungry-forest-wallpaper-by-bpsola-dpbvp.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './public/images/uploads',
  filename: 'fecd4b0cdb2420bb15ab8e3ff2f12805',
  path: 'public/images/uploads/fecd4b0cdb2420bb15ab8e3ff2f12805',
  size: 1663410 }`

noimage.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you working off the Udemy Node project series? Your codes look similar to mine and I'm stuck with the multer file uploading too. Are you seeing files in the upload directory?

There are files in the upload directory for me. But when I check my mongodb, the image section is blank.

Comment: Yes i m learning from that series
but when i used `app.use(multer({dest:'./public/images/uploads'}).single('mainimage'));`
its working

`if(req.file){
 var mainImageOriginalName  = req.file.originalname;
 var mainImageName    = req.file.filename;
 var mainImageMime    = req.file.mimetype;
 var mainImagePath    = req.file.path;
 var mainImageExt    = req.file.extension;
 var mainImageSize    = req.file.size;
 // console.log(mainImageName);
} else{
 var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
 // console.log(req.file.filename);
}`


now its working

how to upload multiple images on a same page